# How can I send multiple arrays of bytes from client to tcp server sequentially in rust?

Tags: rust, tcp

I want to send 2 Strings converted to bytes sequentially to the server via the TCP protocoll like this:

client:

```rust
let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:8080")?;

socket.write("Name".as_bytes())?;
socket.write("Password".as_bytes())?;

let mut buffer = [0; 8];
let len = stream.read(&mut buffer)?;

let buf = &mut buffer[..len];
```

server:

```
let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?;
for stream in listener.incoming() {
    thread::spawn(move || -> std::io::Result<()> {
        let mut name = [0; 256]; // 256 Byte Buffer for name
        stream.read(&mut name)?;

        let mut password = [0; 256]; // 256 Byte Buffer for password
        stream.read(&mut password)?;

        stream.write(&[2; 8])?;

        Ok(())
    });
}
```

But if I do it like this the server will only recieve the name, but not the password.

It works when I let the thread sleep for 1ms between sending the name and password, but that seems like a bad solution and im not sure if it works when the server does not run as localhost.

I also don't like to combine "Name" and "Password" to one array of bytes to be sent at once, because I already thought how to server should work and it is completely based on the idea, that the client sends multiple, small packages that will get proccessed sequentially.

Is this even possible or is it generally something very stupid to do with TCP?

Comment: Note that with TCP, a single `write` could be split in multiple `read`, and multiple `write`s could correspond to a single `read`. You have no control over that, so your protocol is broken by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

Instead of using `stream.read()` on the serverside I had to use `stream.read_exact()`.

then it will read until 256 bytes were sent from the client (number of bytes = length of buffer)

This way It cant return the length of the recieved buffer, but I circumvented this problem, by writing the length into the first byte of the buffer (only 256 byte big buffers are possible, tho)